# How to get a number of availability zones in a particular Azure region using Az PowerShell CLI?

Tags: azure-availability-zones

My service is present in many Azure regions, some of them have Availability Zones, some don't. Upon creation I'd like to use max number of availability zones available. But it is not clear how to get this information using Az PowerShell CLI.